# Is JQuery still evaluating selectors RTL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

There is so much information about JQuery selectors on the net, that I'm confused about what is the current state-of-the-art regarding JQuery selector performance.

- Is JQuery still evaluating selectors RTL?

Regardless of this, ...

- is `('#context').find('.inner') still faster than ('#context .inner')`?
- is `('li') still faster than ('.classOnAllAndOnlyOnLiElements')`?

I know I can write my own JSPerf performance evaluation, however, I'm scared the kind of DOM tree I would use is not suited for such a test (as I'm no professional and therefore don't know what things I need to generate, e.g. # DOM tree levels, # of DOM tree elements, etc.)

Hope somebody can answer my questions from a theoretical point of view and by knowing more about the JQuery implementation than by a simple performance evaluation which may only be the answer to one specific DOM tree.

Comment: Why won't you open jquery source and see what it is doing ?

Comment: Write a test that executes in your own application's DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

[jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) is as as theoretical as an answer from anyone who can answer your question.

We can only tell you how jQuery is written but without tests on your DOM, it's of no use - just like jsPerf...

However, I would still use jsPerf and do an abstract test on some small DOM in multiple browsers, so you have an *idea* how to best code your application **regardless of its size** - which should be a generic idea for ***any*** web development anyway.

Coding in general shouldn't be tied to the size of your DOM, it should be tied to your product's performance - and that's where tools like jsPerf can help *a lot*

;-)

Answer (score 0):

Important part here is that in case of simple selectors, and your selectors are simple, jquery uses  `*MatchesSelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` if it is available and it is obviously dependent on browser. So the only way to know is profile it in all browsers you are going to use.

From jquery source:

```
 ....
 matches = docElem.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    docElem.mozMatchesSelector ||
    docElem.oMatchesSelector ||
    docElem.msMatchesSelector,
 ....
 jQuery.extend({
find: function( selector, context, results, seed ) {
    ...
    if ( seed ) {
        while ( (elem = seed[i++]) ) {
            if ( jQuery.find.matchesSelector(elem, selector) ) {
                results.push( elem );
            }
        }
    } else {
        jQuery.merge( results, context.querySelectorAll(selector) );
    }

    return results;
}
   ....
 })
 ...
 jQuery.extend( jQuery.find, {
matches: function( expr, elements ) {
    return jQuery.find( expr, null, null, elements );
},
matchesSelector: function( elem, expr ) {
    return matches.call( elem, expr );
},
attr: function( elem, name ) {
    return elem.getAttribute( name );
}
 });
```